# VMWare Ubuntu 18.04 connected to LAN but no network card available in gnome e.g. for sharing

Tags: networking, gnome, vmware

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome running as a VM.
The network adapter is recognized as "ens160" and LAN is available/does work fine.

When I try to set up "Sharing" through the GUI I can't enable it,
maybe because there is no network adapter listed - I think.

How can I fix this?
Does anyone have an idea?

I try to set up VINO ....

Thanks in advance!

Network

[Sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyVWJ.png)

[Network details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuzA1.png)

Answer (score 1):

It would seem NetworkManager is not managing the network interface.

In a terminal, run "nmcli device status"

You should see your network interface in green, with a state of connected.

If you see the state as unmanaged, run "nmcli device set devicename managed true" to allow NetworkManager to latch on.

Note, by default NetworkManager ignores any devices listed in /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: Hi Peter, setting it to managed did not work, still grey/unmanaged....

Comment: I see, I will remove it from /etc/network/interfaces and try it.

Comment: This did not let appear any network card in the GUI :(

Comment: What was the result of the nmcli device status command?